# When replacing a slash (\) with a slash (/) it changes it to ( )

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace a backslash with a normal slash with the following code:

```
20180409_100219_13\000388.png".replace(String.fromCharCode(92),String.fromCharCode(92,92));
```

> --output-- "20180409_100219_13 008.png"

```
20180409_100219_13\000388.png".replace(/\\\\/, "/");
```

> --output-- "20180409_100219_13 008.png"

Why does this happen?

the output I wanted:

> 20180409_100219_13/008.png

Comment: Try simply `console.log("20180409_100219_13\000388.png")`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `20180409_100219_13\000388.png` to `20180409_100219_13\\000388.png` with double `\` so that you can replace that with `/`. This is because while you use `\` in string you need to escape that with an additional `\` so use two `\`.

```js
var str = "20180409_100219_13\\000388.png";
str = str.replace(/\\/, "/");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: \ to \\  How am I going to translate this?I'm getting the same error again.

var str = "20180409_100219_13\000388.png";
str = str.replace(/\\/, "\\");
console.log(str);

"20180409_100219_13\000388.png".replace(String.fromCharCode(92),String.fromCharCode(92,92));

--output-- "20180409_100219_13  388.png"

Comment: @hacı `\0` in a **string literal** is an escape sequence for a `NUL` byte! The string literal `"\0"` is one character long, which is a `NUL` byte. You need to write `"\\0"` **in the string literal** if you want your string to contain "backslash zero". You cannot replace this after the fact.

Comment: @deceze I do not fully understand what you mean.